# What's the formal name of 'search committee' in a cover letter for postdoc application?

Tags: application-cover-letter

When writing a cover letter for my postdoc application, I have a question about how to write the recipent's name at the beginning of the letter. It's not a specfic person, but a committee. But I don't know the formal name of the committe (it is not provided in the info page). Can I just call it "Postdoctoral Search Committee"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I just call it "Postdoctoral Search Committee"?

Yes, that's fine and normal in your situation.

If a specific person is named in the advertisement, use their name.